# File name is null of the mail attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing some code on ASP.NET MVC. I need to send an email with attachment. But the attachment name is null

here is my code.
Note that I don't need to save the uploaded files inside the server.

mathod parameter :

```
List<HttpPostedFileBase> ScreenshotsOfIssueFiles
```

code:

```
List<Attachment> screenshotAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
foreach (var files in ScreenshotsOfIssueFiles)
{
    if (files != null && files.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var attachment = new Attachment(files.InputStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
        disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
        screenshotAttachments.Add(attachment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var attachment = new Attachment(files.InputStream, files.FileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Then your code looks like.   Edited

```
List<Attachment> screenshotAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
    foreach (var files in ScreenshotsOfIssueFiles)
    {
        if (files != null && files.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var attachment = new Attachment(files.InputStream, files.FileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
            disposition.FileName = files.FileName;
            disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
            screenshotAttachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: It's not working still. I debugged the code and found: ContentDisposition.FileName = null and ContentDisposition.size=-1

Comment: Have you checked what you get on files.FileName?

Comment: Yes, it gives the name of the file.

Comment: So, assign it directly not using Path.GetFileName(files.FileName). Check my updated code.